# How can I say 'Formatting needed'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is a word like "enpaĝiginda" correct?

If not, what words could I use to express this?

Comment: Could you provide an example?  Formatting could have various ways of translating.  Context would be a tremendous help here.

Comment: Sure. It will be use with internet pages. Like "That page doesn't follow the given structure, a formatting is needed". And I want to just have one or two words to create a shortcut.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- formatting needed = **aranĝenda**

This is as `aranĝo` means *layout* in this context, and [`aranĝi`](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/arangx.html) is also `pretigi` (make ready). Maybe **rearanĝenda**.

Answer (score 4):

I checked Komputeko, but I have a growing feeling that things are moved around and "developed". Having translated Joomla and related texts for a few years, we ended up using words like "formatigi" for the verb format. From there, one may think in different lines. *Formatting* is "enpaĝigi" but it totally depends on context, set and setting.

For *layout* we use "aspekto" or "trajtaro" depending on what the layout is really about. A general layout of things, like a page, would be aspekto while smaller stuff in a page, like the setup for text would be trajtaro.